# Nikah certificates and boundaries

Tags: nikah

Last year I met a guy that I liked and to make our relationship halal, we got married in a masjid with two witnesses and we made the nikah certificate but without my parents knowledge.

We have now been together for two years and but we never consummated our marriage.  (we never had intercourse) It was just to make our relationship halal.

Now we are engaged in front of our family but they don’t know we have a nikah certificate. Our families want us to do the “nikah” night after the marriage celebration but technically we can do it before according to Islam or not yet?

Comment: Like @Medi1Saif has mentioned in his answer, the best response to your answer would be from a Mufti your husband or close ones can meet and discuss the issue with. But at the same breath, I'd advise that as you have had the patience to wait for two years, why not a just a little longer. Inshallah there is khair for you as it will help avoid the bad tongues in the society.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better having a nikah with all conditions! If according to the school of fiqh both of you are following the agreement of your (I suppose you are female) guardian is not necessary you are already married with no doubts about the validity of marriage, if not you should consider telling your parents and have a correct nikah.

Be aware that you should never fear being truthful and correcting what was wrong. Most schools of fiqh consider the agreement of the guardian as essential an imam of a mosque can only replace him under certain conditions, which today are hardly applicable, but a woman should always seek the agreement of her guardian first. Also be aware that even if you married without the agreement of your guardian a shari'a court would hardly consider separating you if for example you were already having kids or being pregnant.

And finally a nikah certificate is not a requirement for a marriage being valid in Islam as it is an innovation of our modern times which has clear benefits and therefore shouldn't be regarded as bid'ah. However it might be a requirement for a civil notification or record of a marriage which declare this marriage as legal according the local law.

Comment: Salam thank you for the information

Comment: So technically we can consume our marriage right ? Jazakallahu khairan 

Comment: @RajaeRajy I can't say neither yes nor no as I don't know your maddhab and I'm not a mufti.